# windows cluster - Service Principle Name but no cluster service?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2012, cluster

I used to be detecting which servers in our big environment are clusters or cluster nodes by checking *ServicePrincipalName* value of their AD objects if it is a string containing MSServerClusterMgmtAPI or MSServerCluster like this:

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\tsclient\h\packages> get-adcomputer servername -properties * |select name,serviceprincipalname|ft -wrap

name     serviceprincipalname
----     --------------------
servername {MSSQLSvc/servername.ourdomain.com:BMXWEB, MSSQLSvc/servername.ourdomain.com:1433, MSServerClusterMgmtAPI/servername, MSServerClusterMgmtAPI/servername.ourdomain.com...}
```

There are two servers in one domain with this value in serviceprincipalname which I thought are in cluster, but now it seems like they are not, because ClusSvc Cluster Service is NOT running and no cluster role is installed.
So I am not sure what these values mean and if they indicate anything. Are these servers not in cluster or were they before and it was uninstalled, but this value didn't change?

As you can see no failover cluster manager or service is there

[image]

Comment: What are you getting by executing your script? It would also be nice to provide the script.

Comment: I am sorry, it's not a script but just one command. Anybody who knows get-adcomputer can test it. But I will edit the post with some example...

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. Just edit and will upvote, that was a mistake from my side.

Answer (score 2):

At some point these servers had a cluster configuration applied. I am guessing someone did not finish cleanup. If you are not using a LDAP filter with Get-ADComputer I assume your query will return disabled computer accounts. According to the documentation below computer account objects are not deleted unless you do it intentionally during cleanup. To add clarification to your question: "Does removing a failover cluster remove AD attributes from the computer object in Active Directory?" The answer is no.

- Server 2008 - [Dealing with Accounts After a Failover Cluster is Destroyed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/cc771174(v=ws.10))
- Server 2016 - [Remove-Cluster](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/remove-cluster?view=win10-ps)

Comment: please clarify which objects you mean that were not cleaned up, because if I understand it right the serviceprincipalname is just an attribute of a computer object in AD, so removing of cluster service from a server does not mean that it's computer object in AD would be deleted! But reading the article it seems like those commands probably would result in updating this attribute and removing those lines about cluster...

Comment: The objects that were not cleaned up are the servers (computers) in Active Directory. If you use `-CleanupAD` parameter the Cluster configuration will be removed from the nodes (computer objects) and the cluster objects (computer objects) will be deleted from Active Directory. I opened an issue on GitHub to add clarification.